# Select from table where=$variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to learn PHP/MySql and create a simple "website".

I have a problem while i try to print a row from a Select. I created a Database with the table "Utenti" and i want to select an username from it.

```
$username='Prova';
// In my database there is a record with username "Prova"

require 'connessione_db.php';
// I connect Php to the Database in another file

mysqli_select_db ($conn, $dbname);

$checkusername= "SELECT username FROM utenti WHERE username= '$username' ";
// when i write "Where username='Prova' " there aren't problem.

$username_result=mysqli_query($conn,$checkusername);

if (mysqli_num_rows($username_result) > 0) {
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($username_result)) {
                echo $rows['username'];
        }
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

With actual code the result is "no", but if i write:

```
... where username='Prova'";
```

the result is "Prova".

I tried to change the code reading user's solutions without success. I tried:

```
" ... Where username='" .$username. "'";
```

or

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
```

and other useless advice.

Comment: `..username='" .$username. "'"` is the same as `username= '$username' "`. Using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` makes no difference here, since there's nothing to escape (though you should really be using a prepared statement instead). There's nothing in the question that suggests that you would get different results when running a hard-coded value and a variable with that exact same variable. Is there something else you're not showing in the question?

Comment: I add the entire code, i left out only <?php and ?> Previously i used a similar code but the variable was an integer type and the code doesn't give problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you're adressing to your sql server you're using string so you jsut need to merge two strings so `username='" .$username. "'"` should work just fine. What might work is something like `"...username='{$username}"`. You should debug this string by using `error.log($checkusername)` what's wrong with your string. Also what version of php you currently using? Best stable version are `5.6` or `7.3.4` although 7+ versions isn't popular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer <3.
I'm using PHP 7.3.1.
I have tried to merge the strings with a point but it doesn't work;
I also tried to add braces "{$username}" ...
How can i use the "error.log"? I Should write it after the select of the database?

Comment: @Yann you should use `error.log` before your sql query and then view it in error.log file located somewhere on the server.

Comment: I tried to add error_log in my code:

    '  " error_log($controllousername)= 'SELECT... " '

and when i try to open page get this error: Fatal error: Can't use function return value.

Comment: @Yann You use `error_log` as a function so you pass parameter (in your case it's string) so it's looks like this: `error_log($myString);`. Also I would recommend you read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php) article about that function.

Comment: Yesterday i used this function and i get the fatal error "Can't use function return value". Maybe i'm not understanding you... Anyway, thank you for your patience